# Retrieve chat history between two users from ejabberd server using smack

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd, smack

I am working on a chat application. I am using `smack` library in my android application and `ejabberd` as my XMPP server . I implemented everything I wanted but I couldn't fetch the chat history between two user . Note that I am not talking about `group chat` or `chat room` . Just chat history between two users . Chat history is already enabled in the server and I can fetch the chat history in web , but not in my android application . I have looked all the question related to this topic in SO, but couldn't find a example code .

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How did things go ? any result ?